# textmode 14.04 booting to uefi

Tags: command-line, console

Anyone able to get true textmode working while booting to UEFI?

I"m able to get the legacy mode in textmode by changing grub wit the following.

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Comment the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
3. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"`
4. Uncomment this line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
5. Save the changes, and run `sudo update-grub`

Works for legacy mode, but not for UEFI.